# Why does a single number fail to match a Range object in an array?

Tags: raku

```
> my @numbers = 1, 3, 5;
> 1 ~~ /@numbers/; # 
｢1｣
```

is the same as:

```
> 1 ~~ /1 | 3 | 5/
｢1｣
```

but when the element is a **Range** object, it fails to match:

```
> my @ranges = 1..3.item, 4..6.item;
[1..3 4..6]

> 1 ~~ /@ranges/
Nil
> 1 ~~ /|@ranges/
Nil
> 1 ~~ /||@ranges/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does single number fails to match Range object in array?

Per [the doc](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Quoted_lists_are_LTM_matches):

> The interpolation rules for individual elements [of an array] are the same as for scalars

And per the same doc section the rule for a scalar (that is not a regex) is:

> interpolate the stringified value

A range object such as `1..3` stringifies to `1 2 3`:

```
my $range = 1..3;
put $range;                   # 1 2 3
put so '1'     ~~ / $range /; # False
put so '1 2 3' ~~ / $range /; # True
```

So, as Holli suggests, perhaps instead:

```
my @ranges = flat 1..3, 4..6;
say @ranges;        # [1 2 3 4 5 6]
say 1 ~~ /@ranges/; # ｢1｣
```

Or is there some reason you don't want that? (See also Scimon's comment on Holli's answer.)

Comment: Thanks raiph. so I have to smartmatch against every **Range** object in a for loop.

Comment: @chenyf What's stopping you just flattening anything/everything you push/append/assign/add/whatever to the array used in the match?

Answer (score 4):

When the regex engine sees `/@numbers/` it treats that like an alternation of the array elements, so your first two examples are equivalent.

There just is no such automatism for `Range`s I believe.

Edit: Never mind below, I totally misread the question at first.

```
> my @ranges = 1..3, 4..6;
[1..3 4..6]
> 1 ~~ @ranges[0];
True
> 2 ~~ @ranges[1];
False
> 4 ~~ @ranges[1];
True
> @ranges.first( 5 ~~ * )
4..6
```

See? `@ranges` is a array of, well, ranges (your call to `item` does nothing here). *Theoretically* this *would* hold true if the smartmatch operator were smarter.

```
> 1..3 ~~ @ranges;
False
```

Flattening also doesn't help, because a flat list of ranges is still a list of ranges.

Flattening the ranges themselves is possible, but that simply turns them into Arrays

```
> my @ranges2 = |(1..3), |(4..6)
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Comment: You could do `1 ~~ any(@ranges)` if you want to see if 1 is in any of the ranges of course.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  May be raku just not that smart in such scene.